# Openshift application deployed successfully but not updated

Tags: java, deployment, jboss7.x, openshift

I've been trying forever to deploy a Java application to a JBoss AS 7 server on OpenShift, but, although the deployment log says the application has been deployed successfully, the deploy is not being honoured. An old version of my application is being served to the user and some modules I added under .openshift/config/modules are not taken into account.

I connected through SSH to my application and I can see my deployment under the repo folder, but the WAR under dependencies/jbossas/deployments is not correct, it's the old one.

I just migrated recently to Hibernate, could this be the problem? I'm seriously puzzled here since no errors are getting displayed in the server logs. I even made some modifications in the index.html an are not getting displayed.

The deployment log says:

```
remote: CLIENT_MESSAGE: Artifact: ./ROOT.war is still deploying[K
remote: /var/lib/openshift/534346184382ec47bc00025b/jbossas[K
remote: Artifacts deployed: ./ROOT.war[K
remote: -------------------------[K
remote: Git Post-Receive Result: success[K
remote: Activation status: success[K
remote: Deployment completed with status: success[K
To ssh://534346184382ec47bc00025b@ ...
0db8697..a779ad0  master -> master
Application is available at ...
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That is odd. So you are saying the repo for your application is the same on your client and OS gear BUT the war generated on the gear is not correct?

Is there already a WAR file in your deployables directory in your git repo? If so that would make OpenShift deploy that regardless of what the rest of your repository looked like.